# How to move div onkeypress HTML CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to make an html game where the player can move around the web page but I cannot get the movement to work. I want the player to move on key press. I got the key press to work, I tested it with an alert, but I cant get it to move the div. Here's my code,

```js
function keyPress(){
if(window.event.keyCode == 87){
    document.getElementById("player").style.left = 10 + 'px';
}
if(window.event.keyCode == 83){
  alert("spressed")
}
if(window.event.keyCode == 65){
  alert("apressed")
}
if(window.event.keyCode == 68){
  alert("dpressed")
}
}
```

```css
.player{
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html onkeydown="keyPress()">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="player" id="player">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is probably easy for some of you so I appreciate the help. Thanks : )

Comment: The class "player" must have "position: absolute;" to set the position of the div using attributes like left, right, top or bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the `.player` class has no `position` attribute, you must define the position as `absolute` like that

```
position: absolute;
```

if you want to set the position of the element in relation to its containing block, or use

```
position: fixed;
```

to set the position of the element in relation to the initial containing block.

Working snippet

```js
function keyPress(){
if(window.event.keyCode == 87){
    document.getElementById("player").style.left = 10 + 'px';
}
if(window.event.keyCode == 83){
    document.getElementById("player").style.left = 50 + 'px';
}
if(window.event.keyCode == 65){
    document.getElementById("player").style.left = 100 + 'px';
}
if(window.event.keyCode == 68){
    document.getElementById("player").style.left = 150 + 'px';
}
}
```

```css
.player{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html onkeydown="keyPress()">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="player" id="player">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, you have solved that but I added it and it only moves once. I need it to move every time I click W.

Comment: @I-amcool Ok, so you have to change the js to take the current "left" value from the css and sum it, currently you are simply setting the position to "left: 10px" not adding some left space, for example:

    const currentLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left) || 0;
    document.getElementById("player").style.left = (currentLeft + 10) + 'px';

Comment: This worked, Thank you very much. If anyone wants to see the finished code I posted it on my Github [https://github.com/I-amcool/stack-awnsers-completed-code](https://github.com/I-amcool/stack-awnsers-completed-code)